# How to create 1 slicer to filter 2 columns on a table

Tags: powerbi

I have a table which has 2 columns with has same values.

| Date | Source | Destination |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Nov 2022 | New York | London |
| Nov 2022 | London | Chicago |
| Nov 2022 | Chicago | Seattle |
| Nov 2022 | Seattle | New York |
| Nov 2022 | Paris | London |

I create a `Dimension` table which has the set of cities between Source & Destination.

| CityDimension |
| --- |
| New York |
| Seattle |
| London |
| Chicago |
| Paris |

How can I create a slider which filter both `Source` and `Destation`?
e.g. if Seattle is selected in the slider, these rows will show

| Date | Source | Destination |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Nov 2022 | Chicago | Seattle |
| Nov 2022 | Seattle | New York |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### If your `CityDimension` is related to your table

For this case, you can establish two relationships to the table, one will be active (default) and one will be inactive (activated when needed), and you will add a measure that returns a value if it is valid in the chosen selected city context.

It is up to you whether `CityDimension` should by default filter `'Table'[Destination]` or `'Table'[Source]`. In my model, the *active* relationship is between `CityDimension` and `Source`, and the *passive* is to `Destination`.

[image]

You will need to adjust your DAX according to your active/passive relationships, but you can define a measure like this to use as a filtering basis:

```
Show = 
VAR _dst =
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS ( 'Table' ),
        USERELATIONSHIP ( CityDimension[Destination] , 'Table'[Destination] ) // Uses PASSIVE relationship
    )
VAR _src =
    CALCULATE ( COUNTROWS ( 'Table' ) ) // Uses ACTIVE relationship
RETURN
    IF ( _dst || _src, 1 )
```

This measure must then be physically added to your table:

[image]

Depending on your requirements this may be inelegant! You can consider naming the table visual column something short like `#` and set conditional formatting on the column to match the column background and font, but it is difficult to hide it altogether.

##### If your `CityDimension` is not related to your table

For this case, it is required that your `CityDimension` table is *unrelated* to your fact table. If this is the case, you can add a measure that filters the table based on the selection in `CityDimension` using `TREATAS` to propagate your filters properly from dimension to fact:

```
Show =
VAR _dst =
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS ( 'Table' ),
        TREATAS ( VALUES ( CityDimension[Destination] ), 'Table'[Destination] )
    )
VAR _src =
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS ( 'Table' ),
        TREATAS ( VALUES ( CityDimension[Destination] ), 'Table'[Source] )
    )
RETURN
    IF ( _dst || _src, 1 )
```

Add this measure as a filter to the table visual, and as with the other solution, set it to `Show is 1`, but for this solution the measure does not have to be in the table itself, so it is perhaps a better one, depending on your requirements:

[image]

You can always consider adding this "loose" single-column table to your data model to enable this specific use-case.

Comment: Thanks. But adding a measure, I can't use that in  a 'Slicer'. Meaning , I want a slider to have all the city and I can click on 1 city in the slider and the table of Source /Destination will get filtered.

Comment: That’s exactly what I have shown you to do.